# What's the best way to package a vb6/vb.net hybrid application?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

I've been working on a project for my company that's completely implemented in VB6. However, we've been transitioning small parts of it over into VB.NET (v4.0). Previously, we would simply use the Package and Deployment Wizard to bundle everything up into a single setup executable, but I'm not confident that it will be enough this time. If it can be helped, we'd like for the setup to check if the .NET framework is installed on the target machine and then install it if it is not, which I'm pretty sure Package and Deployment Wizard cannot do.

I've been reading up on INNO scripting since it seems an appropriate alternative for packaging both VB.NET and VB6 projects, but it has a lot of warnings about including the wrong or unnecessary dll files. I'm a complete noob and this doesn't instill a great deal of confidence in me. I don't want our customers to run our installer and have their computers crash as a direct result.

I've been doing my own research (apologies in advance if this question has already been asked, I didn't see any relevant threads), but this is all totally virgin territory for me. What tools and instructions does this site recommend for accomplishing the things that I want? Does VB.NET come with any tools for this sort of thing, or am I pretty much on my own?

Comment: There are no idiot-proof packaging tools, deployment can be a topic almost as complex as simple software development.  Don't expect to do it properly without some investment in time and experience.  There is nothing like a newb's "no no script" setup to trash a user's system either.  Copy/paste of bad sample scripts off the web screw up a lot of people.  If you really want to choose that route be sure to spend time learning to use it properly.

Comment: Bob's completely right.  Something I just thought of is download VMWare and set up some virtual machines.  When I did windows development I had 2 VMs running for testing installs.  One was a fresh install.  The other was upgrading an existing app.  Saved my butt a few times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

I decided, appropriately enough, to take a hybrid approach. I'm using inno to build the setup.exe, but inside of that setup I'm packaging the setup file that's generated by P&DW. The P&DW takes care of all the dll crap for me, we already know it works so I don't have to worry about screwing it up, and I can just focus on making all the .NET portions install properly. It is a little bit goofy having an installer run during another installer, but it's actually a pretty small compromise, considering.

Thanks for all the tips, everybody!

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out something like [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/)  It will help you package and deploy your application.  You can set dependencies like .Net 4.0 that it will ensure that it is installed before your app is.  There's always InstallShield, but the cost and functionality is probably overkill at this time.

Unfortunately, with all the development of better languages, better IDEs, more developer tools, it seems as if installation tools are lagging considerably.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I'll check it out.

I should also mention that I'm using the express (ie free) version of Visual Studio to do my work in. I admit that I don't really know what sort of packaging tools come with the professional version. For all I know, it can do everything that I need.

Comment: It might, but in my opinion, you're better off with a 3rd party tool.  The MS one seems to not be that great.  That said, I've delivered applications (commercial and internal) using both methods

Comment: Those .Net Express SKUs only have the bare minimum to let you create ClickOnce packages as far as I recall.  That may not be enough flexibility to meet your needs.

Comment: Second Bob's comment. You're gonna bang into walls at every turn trying to do something sophisticated with the inthe box install tools of VS. Pick up Installshield or better yet, Wise. InnoSetup is nice, and it's free, but it can be lacking when you start talking about doing corporate deployments. Most larger companies want a plain ol' MSI file that they can deploy using automated deployment tools. MSI's make that easier, other installers often aren't as easy to work into automatic deployments.

Answer (score 1):

Might also look at [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/).  We use it for our client-installations (our app is fully .net, but it doesn't matter).

From the linked page:

The Windows Installer XML (WiX) is a toolset that builds Windows installation packages from XML source code. The toolset supports a command line environment that developers may integrate into their build processes to build MSI and MSM setup packages.